# What is the proper way to add custom Controls to the Eclipse toolbar (using WorkbenchWindowControlContribution)?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I'm developing a set of Eclipse plugins, one of which is responsible for adding a toolbar to the Eclipse workspace.

While adding new commands (and the corresponding buttons) can be done in `plugin.xml`, I also need a text box and a label, which requires the addition of a `Control` to the `plugin.xml`, plus an implementation in Java that extends `org.eclipse.ui.menus.WorkbenchWindowControlContribution`. In practice, this comes down to overriding `createControl(Composite parent)` in the subclass.

This part is clear to me. The problem is that I'm not sure what type of Control object I should return.

I have tried the following:

- Create a `ToolBarManager`, add an SWT `Label` and an STW `Text` to it (both wrapped in separate `ControlContribution` objects), and return the toolbar obtained by `ToolBarManager.createControl(parent)`:

  ```
  @Override
  protected Control createControl(Composite parent)
  {
      ToolBarManager manager = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
      LabelContributionItem labelItem = new LabelContributionItem("myLabelId");
      manager.add(labelItem);
      TextContributionItem textItem = new TextContributionItem("myTextId");
      manager.add(textItem);
      ToolBar toolbar = manager.createControl(parent);
      return toolbar;
   }
  ```

  However, the label is not positioned correctly:

  [image: Result using ToolBarManager]
- Use a `GridLayout` as the control to return (code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10331418/)):

  ```
  @Override
  protected Control createControl(Composite parent)
  {

       Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.SINGLE);
       GridLayout compositeLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
       compositeLayout.marginTop = -1;
       compositeLayout.marginBottom = 0;
       compositeLayout.marginLeft = 5;
       compositeLayout.marginWidth = 0;
       composite.setLayout(compositeLayout);
       Label myLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
       myLabel.setText("myLabel");
       Text myText = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
       myText.setText("myText");
       return composite;
  }
  ```

  The result is an incorrectly sized and aligned text box, plus a border around the label (rightmost text box added for comparison):

  [image: Result using Composite with GridLayout]

I also tried some other combinations and layouts, but cannot get this to work properly. Furthermore, I'd like to add a [ControlDecoration](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ffieldassist%2FControlDecoration.html) to the text box, like this:

[image: Control Decoration]

For the ControlDecoration's mouseover text to work properly, there needs to be margin space to the left of the text box ([source](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ffieldassist%2FControlDecoration.html)):

> Clients using ControlDecoration should typically ensure that enough margin space is reserved for a decoration

Adding this space has also proved troublesome, except when using the GridLayout's `marginLeft` parameter (but GridLayout gave the alignment problems described above).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with labels. Use `CLabel` if you want to add text to the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to first create a standalone `Composite` that contains the desired controls and decorations independantly of the workbench contribution.
There you can test the layout in a simple `Shell` until it looks like how it should.

As far as I understood your question, this is how the controls should be layed out:

```java
Composite composite = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE );
composite.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );
composite.setBackground( composite.getDisplay().getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_GREEN ) );
Label label = new Label( composite, SWT.NONE );
label.setText( "MyLabel" );
Text text = new Text( composite, SWT.BORDER );
text.setText( "my text" );
ControlDecoration decoration = new ControlDecoration( text, SWT.TOP | SWT.LEFT );
FieldDecorationRegistry registry = FieldDecorationRegistry.getDefault();
FieldDecoration fieldDecoration = registry.getFieldDecoration( DEC_CONTENT_PROPOSAL );
decoration.setImage( fieldDecoration.getImage() );
label.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false ) );
GridData gridData = new GridData( SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false );
gridData.horizontalIndent = 10;
text.setLayoutData( gridData );
```

Then you can attempt to contribute the controls to the workbench. The extension should be specified as described in this post: [Contributed control to the status bar not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202990/contributed-control-to-the-status-bar-not-visible)

`createControl()` should return the above mentioned composite and look like this

```
protected Control createControl( Composite parent ) {
  Composite composite = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE );
  // ... create label, text, decoration as above
  return composite;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a tool item of type SWT.SEPARATOR and then attach the label to that. The following code demonstrates this:

```
public static ToolItem createToolBarLabel(ToolBar toolBar, String text, int width) {
    ToolItem labelItem = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.SEPARATOR);
    CLabel label = new CLabel(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText(text);
    labelItem.setWidth(width);
    labelItem.setControl(label);

    return labelItem;
}
```